# recyclerView in the viewpager2 will auto scroll up after back from next page in the navigation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, navigation

the viewpager2 layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/home_viewpager2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/home_tab" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

the viewpager2's adapter creates two fragments which contain a recyclerView
fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/sub_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

scroll to the bottom of the recyclerView and click one item to navigate to next page and click system back button, the recyclerView will auto scroll one item which only happened at the recyclerView's bottom

Comment: I've encountered the same problem. It specifically happens when I call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, then the RecyclerView scrolls up. Did you ever get a fix for this?

Comment: Found a work around. The `ViewPager2` has variable height, and when top level ConstraintLayout remeasures, RecyclerView doesn't keep its scroll position. Best work around I think is to wrap ViewPager2 in a FrameLayout. That keeps the child views from remeasuring. You could also manually set the height of ViewPager2 after a full measure/layout pass. 

Same issue here, with more possible solutions in comments: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52487038/324625

Comment: @lotz did you found any solution?